# Random order at three-column Slick Slider

Tags: views, 8

I want to show random content on a slick slider which has three a three column layout (three content elements next to each other) on each slide.

If I set the views' sort criteria to RANDOM it will randomize the slides itself but not the content (the content and order on each slide remain the same).

Is there a way to randomize the content of each slide aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution:

The randomize option has to be enabled in the slick options instead of the view's sort-criteria. 
We can either define a optionset to use it in different views (the optionsets have to be set at *Configuration -> Media -> Slick*) or we override the default-optionset in the view configuration itself (*View -> Edit -> Format -> Settings next to Slick Carousel*).